# Предобработка данных из базы данных, перед их выводом в HTML шаблон Django

Tags: python, django

Всем привет!

---

В моем проекте есть необходимость вывода всех записей из таблицы в БД на страничку. Этот кейс закрыть легко, но проблема в том, что в записи присутсвует дата, которую нужно выводить в формате дд-мм-гггг, а не гггг-мм-дд.

---

Окей, написать функцию, которая это все обработает - легко, но каким образом это дело передать в `context`? Просто изначально я туда передаю все записи нужной мне таблицы:

```
records = IpcArchive.objects.all()
context = {
    "all_records": records,
}
```

Далее, уже в самом шаблоне, я через `for` бегу по `all_records` и вывожу нужные мне поля, но я не представляю, куда мне вставить обработчик для дат.

---

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить данную проблему... Есть идея, чтобы сразу через view рендерить HTML шаблон, но не будет ли это костыльно?

Comment: Настройки представления даты, насколько я помню, присутствуют в файле settings. Также вы можете написать метод модели с кастомным выводом данных и обращаться к нему из шаблона.

Comment: @rpe4ka722, Спасибо за ответ! Покопаюсь, разберусь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, как указал @rpe4ka722, в `settings` есть настройка [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#date-format) (и ее `datetime`-товарищ `DATETIME_FORMAT`, которая задает формат дат во всей системе.

Синтаксис [указан в документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std-templatefilter-date).

Во-вторых, в самих шаблонах при использовании переменных вам доступны уже встроенные фильтры. Для вашего случая нам нужен фильтр [date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#date). (да, это та же страничка, что и выше. Встроенные фильтры умеют очень многое, советую пробежаться по ним, чтобы иметь примерное представление).

Таким образом, в нашем шаблоне это может выглядеть так:

```
{% for item in all_records %} 
    {{item.somedate|date:"%d-%m-%Y"}}
{% endfor %}
```

Если функционала встроенных фильтров вам не хватит, можно легко [создать свои фильтры](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Ну и в третьих, вы можете создать собственный list или другую структуру, в которую положите нужные обработанные данные:

```
records = IpcArchive.objects.all()
modified_records = []
for rec in records:
    new_record = ... # тут мы что-то считаем или преобразуем и т.д.
    modified_records.append(new_record)
context = {
    "all_records": modified_records,
}
```

Еще один доступный путь - через [аннотации и агрегацию](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/), но это скорее о преобразовании query, чем о том, что вам нужно.

Как видите, доступных способов много, можно выбирать то, что больше подходит и удобно вам.